# Yeoman Webapp in combination with Assemble

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, grunt-assemble

I'm trying to get the default Yeoman Webapp to work with Assemble.io.
I followed this tutorial [Using assemble.io with yeoman.io’s webapp Gruntfile](http://www.fettblog.eu/blog/2013/09/02/using-assemble-io-with-yeoman-ios-webapp-gruntfile/)

Got it up & running (partially), the first problem I have is that livereload isn't kicking in when changes are made to the .hbs files. When I manually refresh, I can see the changes that were made.

This is my [Grunt file](https://gist.github.com/ThinkGraphical/7240816).

Second problem is that 'grunt build' gives me the following error:

`Running "requirejs:dist" (requirejs) task
{ [Error: Error: Missing either an "out" or "dir" config value. If using "appDir" for a full project optimization, use "dir". If you want to optimize to one file, use "out".
    at Function.build.createConfig ([MY DIRECTORY]/node_modules/grunt-contrib-requirejs/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:25109:19)
]
  originalError: [Error: Missing either an "out" or "dir" config value. If using "appDir" for a full project optimization, use "dir". If you want to optimize to one file, use "out".] }`

I googled around & when I add the following to requirejs:dist:options
`appDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/', dir: 'build'`

Then this error is solved, but the next appears:
 `No "concat" targets found.

Warning: Task "concat" failed. 
Use --force to continue.`

Versions:

`Yeoman 1.0.4

Node 0.10.21

Bower 1.2.7

Grunt-cli 0.1.9

Grunt 0.4.1`

Anyone seeing the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this line](https://gist.github.com/ThinkGraphical/7240816#file-gistfile1-js-L370) in your gist. It's trying to call a task called `concat` in your Gruntfile, but that task doesn't exist. There may have been a change with the Yeoman webapp generator or you might have had a copy/paste issue or something. The `assemble` part of your Gruntfile looks fine.

I think you can remove the `concat` and carry on.